# Saber cuando una fecha pertenece a un día de la semana específico

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

Tengo el siguiente código en AngularJS:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope) {
  $scope.semaFecha = [];
  //inicio ejemplo fechas
  $scope.fechas = [{
    "fechaInicio": "01-04-2016"
  }, {
    "fechaFin": "05-08-2016"
  }];
  for (w = 0; w < $scope.fechas.length; w++) {
    if($scope.fechas[w].fechaInicio !=null){
      $rootScope.lo = moment($scope.fechas[w].fechaInicio, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
    }
    if($scope.fechas[w].fechaFin !=null){
      $rootScope.la = moment($scope.fechas[w].fechaFin, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('M-D-YYYY');
    }
  }
  var enumerateDaysBetweenDates = function(startDate, endDate) {
      var now = startDate, dates = [];

     while (now.format('M-D-YYYY') <= endDate) {
            dates.push(now.format('M-D-YYYY'));//devuelvo todo en formato (Abril-1-2016)
            now.add('days', 1);//sumo un dia
        }
      return dates;
  };
  var results = enumerateDaysBetweenDates($rootScope.lo, $rootScope.la);//results guarda el array dates
  var diaBusqueda="martes";
  for(var p = 0; p < results.length; p++){
    var dia= results[p] //Como formateo cada posicion a formato ej: Abril-martes-2016 ? 
    alert(dia);
  }
});
```

Lo que quiero realizar es filtrar todos los días martes que se encuentran dentro de la variable results. Lo que he hecho hasta el momento es imprimir en un alert cada valor de results.

Pero para buscar los días martes deseo saber como cambio ese formato a `Abril-martes-2016` para que luego se pueda agregar a otro arreglo esos días filtrados pero con un nuevo formato similar a `5/abr./2016`.

Answer (score 1):

Hay dos métodos que te permiten saber el día de la semana [weekday](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/weekday/) y [day](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/).

La diferencia entre ambos es que el primero te da el día de la semana teniendo en cuenta la configuración local y el segundo no.

En algunas regiones por defecto o a decisión del usuario en la configuración del sistema se puede establecer el domingo o el lunes como primer día de la semana. Teniendo en cuenta esta configuración puede ser que el martes sea el segundo o el tercer día. En tu caso solo estas interesado en saber si es martes o no independientemente de la configuración por lo que debes usar

```
if (results.day() === 2) // Es un martes
```

Las fechas que cumplan esa condición son los martes `(0:domingo - 7:sábado)`.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    moment.locale('es');
    $scope.semaFecha = [];
    //inicio ejemplo fechas
    $scope.fechas = [{
      "fechaInicio": "01-04-2016"
    }, {
      "fechaFin": "05-08-2016"
    }];
    for (w = 0; w < $scope.fechas.length; w++) {
      if ($scope.fechas[w].fechaInicio != null) {
        $rootScope.lo = moment($scope.fechas[w].fechaInicio, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
      }
      if ($scope.fechas[w].fechaFin != null) {
        $rootScope.la = moment($scope.fechas[w].fechaFin, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('M-D-YYYY');
      }
    }
    var enumerateDaysBetweenDates = function(startDate, endDate) {
      var now = startDate,
        dates = [];

      while (now.format('M-D-YYYY') <= endDate) {
        dates.push(now.format('M-D-YYYY')); //devuelvo todo en formato (Abril-1-2016)
        now.add(1, 'days'); //sumo un dia
      }
      return dates;
    };
    var results = enumerateDaysBetweenDates($rootScope.lo, $rootScope.la); //results guarda el array dates
    var diaBusqueda = 2; // Equivale a martes
    for (var p = 0; p < results.length; p++) {
      var current = moment(results[p]);
      if (current.day() === diaBusqueda) {
        console.log(current.format('MMMM-dddd-YYYY'), '<-', current.format('M-D-YYYY'));
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Deberías echarle un vistazo a la documentación, ya que es muy clara, de igual forma a veces uno se enreda, y según entendí tu lo que quieres es que te cambie un formato, revisa, corre el ejemplo que te dejé y te saltará un `alert`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   var dia, mes, año, fecha;
    
    dia = moment().format('D'); // 01, 02, 03 ... 31
    mes = moment().format('MMM'); // Ene, Feb ... Dec
    año = moment().format('YYYY'); // 2016, 2017 ... 2018
    
    fecha = dia + "/" + mes + "/" + año;
  
    alert(fecha);
  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```